# XAMPP Either redirects or Errors 403

Tags: php, apache

I have created a wordpress site using XAMPP. When accessing it it would just take me to the Dashboard.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.liamstechsupport.co.uk
    ServerAlias liamstechsupport.co.uk
    DocumentRoot "/www/lts"
</VirtualHost>
```

I then tried adding a VHost as above and it now says 403 Forbidden. (In the Extra v-host config file)

I then tried adding this to the main config:

```
<Directory "\htdocs\lts">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This just came up with the Requested URL was not found on the server.